# Safest way to use eval to parse equations entered by a form

Tags: php, security, eval, formula, equation

I'm wondering what sorts of things should be checked when using **eval()** in PHP to parse a formula that is entered by a user filling out a form. I've seen lots of answers about eval(), but not all of them seem to agree.

Here's what I've gathered:

- Don't use eval for strings (this could be a problem, since it *is* a formula I need to parse)
- Strip the input coming from the form (I'm not entirely sure what things I need to strip)
- Eval may or may not be evil, and is a security risk (are there alternatives for parsing an equation in a string?)

What do you folks think I should do?

**EDIT:** I tried the eval method, and while it does work, the sanitation I used did not support more than two operands. Since I really don't feel like writing my own (possibly insecure) sanitation regex, I'm just going to find and use a pre-written math class instead. Thanks to everyone for the suggestions!

Comment: What kind of formula? A PHP formula? Can you give examples of the possible formulas?

Comment: For mathematical expressions, you could probably run input against a regex like `^[0-9-+/\*%\^\(\) ]+$`. This will allow for mathematical expressions like `1 - (2 * 3 + 1 / (2 ^ (11 % 4)))` but won't allow for `$`, characters, underscores, `::`, `->`, etc.  which prevents the use of variables, functions, and classes.

Comment: An example of the expected formula would be "%U%+%B%-%P%", where anything inside of percent signs is a number loaded by the server.

Comment: What operations are allowed? Standard math? `+-*/%()`

Comment: Further, your post is very helpful. I can run a check against this regex when I check to see if the formulas are valid, then use the method described below by sachleen at parse time. Thank you!

Comment: If sachleen's answer helped, you should really consider making it as solved.

Comment: I was waiting until I figured out how I was going to do things first. I don't really like to jump the gun on marking things solved unless I'm sure it'll help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use `eval`, the [`eval` docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#107377) page on it has some code that will allow you to filter mathematical formulas. But as others, and the PHP docs page, have said, it's not a good idea to use `eval` unless there is no other alternative.

```
<?php

$test = '2+3*pi';

// Remove whitespaces
$test = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $test);

$number = '(?:\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?|pi|π)'; // What is a number
$functions = '(?:sinh?|cosh?|tanh?|abs|acosh?|asinh?|atanh?|exp|log10|deg2rad|rad2deg|sqrt|ceil|floor|round)'; // Allowed PHP functions
$operators = '[+\/*\^%-]'; // Allowed math operators
$regexp = '/^(('.$number.'|'.$functions.'\s*\((?1)+\)|\((?1)+\))(?:'.$operators.'(?2))?)+$/'; // Final regexp, heavily using recursive patterns

if (preg_match($regexp, $q))
{
    $test = preg_replace('!pi|π!', 'pi()', $test); // Replace pi with pi function
    eval('$result = '.$test.';');
}
else
{
    $result = false;
}

?>
```

Comment: A formula would look something like "%U%+%B%-%P%", and the server would load numbers in place of the %x% elements. The method you described above (sans some of the bits that aren't needed) would work well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'm going to put it to use now.

Answer (score 4):

Using EVAL on user input is an excellent way to get your server compromised.  Don't.

The acceptable method is to parse the expression, so you understand every element of it, and then evaluate the expression you parsed.  For mathematical expressions, you can probably find a trusted
package that does just this.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` is always dangerous. As soon as you start blacklisting (filtering), people will find ways to circumvent the assumptions you make in your filter logic. Whitelisting valid expressions is a safer way to go.

But the most effective way to safeguard against somebody abusing the functionality is probably to write a proper parser for mathematical expressions. If the formulas you'd like to support are not too complicated, it's not even that much of a deal if you use a simple top down recursive descent parser approach. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405623/looking-for-a-tutorial-on-recursive-descent-parsing) has some references to get you started. There's also [this article](http://knuth.luther.edu/~leekent/tutorials/ll1.html) that develops a recursive descent parser for a simple calculator (unfortunately, it's in Java, though).